# Should we have a dragonball-multiverse tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

www.dragonball-multiverse.com

Since it is technically a fan work, you can't ask questions about it in the dragonball, dragonball-z or dragonball-super tags.

But it is still a manga, and a widely known and read one with quality on par with the original work. It has been looked at by the original author, has many chapters (and keeps going), an entire website (+ spin-offs) etc.

This is bigger than many mangas that have their own tags here by a large margin, and right now I don,t see how I can ask questions about it under any tag whatsoever.

So what reasons are there for not having this tag?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple, because there are no questions.

Tags exist when there are questions using them. from [the privilege on creating tags](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

> #### What is creating tags?
>
> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. When you choose to create a new tag, you're asking a question in a topic that nobody before you (on this site, at least) ever has.
>
> ...
>
> #### What happens when a new tag is created?
>
> The new tag will now be available for all other community members to use, without needing the new tag privilege. It will also show up in the moderator tools new tag report.
>
> However, note that:
>
> - on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.
> - meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.
>
> Please create new tags responsibly!

as such no *Dragonball Multiverse* questions have been asked. of cause whether or not *Dragonball Multiverse* is on-topic or not is another question which should be asked separately because in the past questions on fan made story content of known series like *Dragonball* have been off-topic

---

also because tonight i have that twitch which makes me want to correct this

> But it is still a manga

no it isn't. as per their [faq](http://www.dragonball-multiverse.com/en/faq.html#faqdbm) under **But you're allowed to do that?...**

> In japan, fan-comics like this one, named Dôjinshi, are very popular and numerous.

this tells me that they aren't a manga like *Dragonball Z* but a Dojinshi like *Magical Girl Noir Quest*, *Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha - Al-Hazard* or *The Legend of the Sword of the Day and the Sword of the Night* and also because they compare *Dragonball Multiverse* with Dojinshi rather than saying it is Dojinshi i'd say it's separate from them but that last part in my opinion.